# How do you run NGSolve GUI within PyCharm?

Tags: user-interface, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I'm trying to run the NGSolve GUI from PyCharm while following their simple tutorial. However, the window appears, but is frozen and the OS thinks it is not responding. The same code runs fine within a Jupyter notebook, but for other reasons I'd prefer to use PyCharm. How can I fix this?

```
import netgen.gui
from ngsolve import Draw, Redraw
Redraw()
input("") # So window doesn't close immediately
```